# JavaScript tradingview miniwidget not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im attempting to embed live charts into a Wordpress site.

Current page Im working on with these charts is: http://www.forexfaction.com/live-currencies/

But the charts will eventually go into a text widget in the sidebar.

The widget is the type TradingView.MiniWidget obtained from Tradingview.com

Example code:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tradingview/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.MiniWidget({
  "container_id": "tv-miniwidget",
  "tabs": [
    "Majors and Minors",
    "Crosses"
  ],
  "symbols": {
  "Majors and Minors": [
  "FX:EURUSD",
  "FX:GBPUSD",
  "FX:USDJPY",
  "FX:USDCHF",
  "FX:AUDUSD",
  "FX:USDCAD"
],
"Crosses": [
  "FX:EURUSD",
  "FX:GBPUSD",
  "FX:USDJPY",
  "FX:USDCHF",
  "FX:AUDUSD",
  "FX:USDCAD"
]
  },
  "width": 300
});
</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Basically the code is not working on the page.

TradingView.widget from the same script works fine, but TradingView.MiniWidget is not doing anything.